# Vista de registros mas recientes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuando quiere hacer una vista que me arroje los registros mas recientes me aparece este error que podria ser? ademas que automaticamente me inserta el top 100 cuando yo no escribi eso

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT sales_order, customer, total_qty, total_por_ticket_qty, model, CONVERT(varchar, date_received, 6) AS Date_Received, CONVERT(varchar, due_date, 6) AS Due_Date, priority, categoria, 
                     CAST(Pz_por_hora AS decimal(11, 2)) AS Pz_por_Hora, CONVERT(varchar, cut, 6) AS Cut, CONVERT(varchar, sw630a830, 6) AS Sw630a830, CONVERT(varchar, sw830a1030, 6) AS Sw830a1030, CONVERT(varchar, sw1030a1230, 
                     6) AS Sw1030a1230, CONVERT(varchar, sw1230a230, 6) AS Sw1230a230, CONVERT(varchar, sw230a430, 6) AS Sw230a430, CONVERT(varchar, sw430a630, 6) AS Sw430a630, CONVERT(varchar, sewing_groupB, 6) 
                     AS Sewing_GroupB, CONVERT(varchar, inspection, 6) AS Inspection, CONVERT(varchar, ready_to_ship, 6) AS Ready_to_ship, shipped_date, shipping_containers, comments, CAST(points_unitarians AS decimal(11, 2)) 
                     AS Points_Unitarians, CAST(total_points AS decimal(11, 2)) AS Total_Points FROM dbo.tbl_Daily ORDER BY id_Daily DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un error, es una advertencia. Básicamente lo que te está diciendo es que en un Vista la clausula `ORDER BY` solo se usa para determinar que filas se van a mostrar, pero no establece el orden en que finalmente estás se vayan a ordenar. En tu ejemplo además estás haciendo un TOP 100 PERCENT, es decir que vas a mostrar todas las filas que retorne la consulta, por lo que podrías directamente obviar la clausula `ORDER BY`.